# Add Numbers To Meet Possible Target

Tags: c#, arrays, list, dynamic-arrays

I've solved a problem to get target number adding two numbers from array. Pretty basic, here's the scenario:

**Input**:

```
arr = [2, 4, 6, 10]
Target = 10
```

**Output**: Indexes retrieved

```
arr = [1, 2] //As 4 + 6 = 10
```

**Code Snippet**:

```
public int[] GetTarget(int[] nums, int target)
{
        List<int> lst = new List<int>(); //List to save number indexes

        int[] newArr = null; //Array initialization
        for (int i = 0; i < (nums.Length - 1); i++) //First loop to iterate numbers from 0 index
        {
            for (int j = (i + 1); j < nums.Length; j++) //Second loop to iterate numbers from 1 index
            {
                if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) //Check target is met adding numbers iterating the loops
                {
                    lst.Add(i); //Save indexes here
                    lst.Add(j);

                    newArr = lst.ToArray(); //Convert the list to array
                }
            }
        }

        return newArr;
    }
}
```

So the above code works fine and it's time complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>) as it iterates the result set using two loops. I was expecting if I can make it using one loop or any alternative way to decrease the iterations.

One more thing, I am using list to save the indexes of the numbers as follows:

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>(); //List to save number indexes
```

Is there any way that I can implement the above without using list (Though internally it uses dynamic array) and use array save those indexes? Something as follows:

```
arr[i] = index;
```

Comment: For part 1 of your question, you'll need math. For the second part, `return new [] { i, j }`.

Comment: Any hints @CodeCaster?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your `for` loop with the following loop. And i don't think List is required to save those indexes.   You can simple return indexes once they are found.

In your code what you are doing is, you are iterating through entire array even though when your indexes are found.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++){
            for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++){
                if(arr[i] + arr[j] == target){
                return new arr[]{i,j};
            }
        }
```

The other Approach to solve this is Using a `Dictionary`. Where keys will be arr[i] and values will be indexes (i). Time Complexity here is O(n) in Worst case.

```
    // Initialise a Dictionary
    Dictionary<int,int> dict = new Dictionary<int,int>();
    for(int i = 0; i<=arr.Length; i++){
        
        // Check if (target - arr[i]) exists in dict
        if(dict.ContainsKey(target - arr[i])){
            //if it exists, return value and i;
            return new int[]{dict[target - arr[i]], i};
        } 
        else
        {
            // otherwise add arr[i] to the dict to iterate further
            dict[arr[i]] = i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Time Complexity here is O(n) in Worst case" -- no, it's `O(n^2)` in the worst case. Dictionary lookup is linear worst case due to collisions being resolved linearly.